# Minimum cost of choosing items from n buckets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have n numbers of buckets. Each bucket contains 3 items - say I1, I2 & I3. Each item has their own cost associated. You have to pick items from each bucket such that items picked from 2 consecutive buckets are not same. What will be the algorithm to find minimum cost of picking n items from n such buckets?

I can think only recursive brute force solution which will explore all costs and find out the minimum of them.

What can be the efficient algorithm to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The state space for dynamic programming can be defined as follows.

```
C[i,j] = minimum cost attainable by choosing items an item from each
         bucket in {1,...,i} where each item index is different from
         the item index in the previous bucket and the item in the
         last bucket is j where i in {1,...,n} and j in {1,2,3}
```

For this state space, we obtain the following recurrence relation, where `I[j,k]` for each `j` in `{1,...,n}` and `k` in `{1,2,3}` denotes the cost of the `k`-th item in bucket `k`.

```
C[i,j] = min { min { C[i-1,2], C[i-1,3] } + I[i,1]: j = 1,
               min { C[i-1,1], C[i-1,3] } + I[i,2]: j = 2,
               min { C[i-1,1], C[i-1,2] } + I[i,3]: j = 3
             }
```

The initial states can be filled by assigning

```
C[1,1] = I[1,1],
C[1,2] = I[1,2],
C[1,3] = I[1,3]
```

and after iteratively filling the state space, the desired value can be found by evaluating the folowing expression.

```
min { C[n,1], C[n,2], C[n,3] }
```